# saving contents of df.show() as a string in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

sc = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
prsn = sc.read.format("csv").option("delimiter", ",").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("C:/Users/amit.suar/IdeaProjects/LearningPyspark/prsn.csv")

prsn.show()

+-------------------------+------------------------+---+-----------+-----------------------------+
|PERSON_MEDIA_CONSUMER_KEY|PERSON_MEDIA_CONSUMER_ID|AGE|GENDER_CODE|EDUCATION_LEVEL_CATEGORY_CODE|
+-------------------------+------------------------+---+-----------+-----------------------------+
|                      101|                 3285854| 15|          1|                            1|
|                      102|                 2313090| 25|          1|                            3|
|                      103|                 2295854| 33|          2|                            6|
|                      104|                 2295854| 33|          2|                            6|
|                      105|                 2471554| 26|          2|                            4|
|                      106|                 2471554| 26|          2|                            4|
+-------------------------+------------------------+---+-----------+-----------------------------+
```

i want to capture this output as a string in a variable..how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is internal/private function that return the same string as `.show()` prints:

```
# Return dataframe as a table of first n records (20 by default)
dataframe._jdf.showString(n, 20)
```

Comment: I tried this.. It is working in my local. But if i try to run it in EMR cluster...It doesn't recognise _jdf...Any other option.